# Найти значение b при известном угле

Tags: python, list

Есть код ответ на который 5.76:

```
a = 20
b = 10
c = 100

angle_deg = np.rad2deg(np.arctan( (a - b) / (c - 1 ) ))
```

Вопрос - как переписать его, если известно что `angle_deg = 5.76`, `a = 10`, `c = 100`, но не известно `b` - тоесть найти `b`.

Comment: Дайте геометрическое определение вопросу. Что такое a, b и с?

Comment: Какое отношение списки имеют к углам? Постарайтесь выражаться яснее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По порядку:

1. `np.deg2rad(angle_deg) = np.arctan((a-b)/(c-1))`
2. `np.tan(np.deg2rad(angle_deg)) = (a-b)/(c-1)`
3. `np.tan(np.deg2rad(angle_deg))*(c-1) = a-b`
4. `np.tan(np.deg2rad(angle_deg))*(c-1)-a = -b`
5. `-np.tan(np.deg2rad(angle_deg))*(c-1)+a = b`

Итог:
`b = -np.tan(np.deg2rad(angle_deg))*(c-1)+a`